# Alienware m14x r2 Drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10, alienware

So I just bought a brand new `Alienware M14xR2` and I love the thing to death.

I decided to install `Ubuntu 12.10 64bit` on it and I was surprised how smoothly the install went, but when I went to check the additional drivers tab it couldn't find anything.

Everything seems to be working fine on my laptop right now but it doesn't have any graphics drivers and the fans seem to kick up more on my Ubuntu partition than my Windows partition.

I downloaded the install file for the official nVidia drivers but I'm holding off installing until I know that's the right answer.

Also if anyone knows a way to control the Alien FX lights on Ubuntu that would be nice but I don't care as much. Thanks so much!

---

Specs:

- 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM (6MB Cache, up to 3.4GHz w/ Turbo Boost 2.0) 2 GB GDDR5
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 650M with Optimus™ 8GB of RAM
- 256 SSD

Comment: you will not install addional driver if everything okay .

Comment: Everything seems fine but it doesn't recognize my graphics which gets to me being an Alienware. I'm going to be do all my graphic intensive stuff on Windows but I do want to experiment with gaming on Linux because of Windows 8. Thanks for the quick comment though.

Comment: I am not that familiar with alienware. Do you have nVidia Optimus graphics? If so, you should check Bumblebee: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: My specs are 

3rd Generation Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM (6MB Cache, up to 3.4GHz w/ Turbo Boost 2.0)

2 GB GDDR5 NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 650M with Optimus™

8GB of RAM and a 256 SSD. I have never used a computer that boots up this fast before.

Comment: how it dowsnt recognize ? what is problem?

Comment: It says with Optimus, so you should definitely check Bumblebee. That is the only thing that works with Nvidia optimus.

Comment: I'm definitely going to try Bumblebee but it'll have to be a little later since it's Thanksgiving (happy Turkey Day everyone!) and my internet connection is pretty much 100kB/s right now. Also when I tried to full screen a Youtube video in Chrome it only filled up the top left corner of the screen and wouldn't play. It works fine in Firefox but I'm a Chrome user, anyone knows a fix to that or do I have to wait for Chrome to be optimized or something?

Comment: if my answer is corrdct please confirm . i think you are using chromium .

Comment: I just installed the Bumblebee drivers following the wiki and I think it worked. The graphics still say unknown but the fans seem to be silent compared to before and everything seems to be working fine including watch Youtube videos in fullscreen in Chrome. For some reason I'm having trouble getting DVD playback to work even though I've installed the restricted extras and VLC but that's not a huge deal. I can't really test the drivers out and typing $ optirun --help doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I logged on to Ubuntu today and got a weird error message saying that I needed to reconfigure my display options. I tried selecting something but nothing seemed to work so I simply restarted and it started up fine but I went to the troubleshoot page of Bumblebee to make sure I had everything. I finally got the optirun command working and ran the glxspheres command which rendered fine and it did say it was rendering on the GPU so I think that everything works. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.martin-juhl.dk/2011/05/optimus-on-linux-problem-solved/ 
a link

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee and install from this link

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think you need a so called "Restricted driver".

I use M14r2 as well and I found that even if you can switch to nvidia official driver, it does not gain much on performance. And there is a noticeable disadvantage for enabling nvidia graphic card: it drains battery and heats up you machine. What I suggest is to use bumblebee(as mentioned by previous post) and disable nvidia card. The battery will last for 2.5 times longer on integrated graphic card and performance difference can be ignored.

Your alienfx problem, here is the link: [PyAlienFx](https://code.google.com/p/pyalienfx/). Note that PyAlienFx works well on 12.10 but not on 13.04.

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for similar things and found this program for the lighting.

http://forum.notebookreview.com/alienware/458528-alienfx-lite-linux-windows-alienfx-tool.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.